# Could not find generator 'active_admin:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I just removed active_admin from my rails app and now trying to add active_admin again.

getmfile:    gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

and I ran this command:

```
rails g active_admin:install
```

and I met this error:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 4200
Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)
Could not find generator 'active_admin:install'. Maybe you meant 'devise:install', 'responders:install' or 'active_record:model'
```

update:
   I ran bundle install but no reaction

update:
   result of rails -T

```
rails about                               # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
rails app:template                        # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template) or URL
rails app:update                          # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just upda...
rails assets:clean[keep]                  # Remove old compiled assets
rails assets:clobber                      # Remove compiled assets
rails assets:environment                  # Load asset compile environment
rails assets:precompile                   # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
rails bower:cache:clean                   # Clear the bower cache ('bower cache clean')
rails bower:clean                         # Attempt to keep only files listed in 'main' of each component's bower.json
rails bower:install[options]              # Install components from bower
rails bower:install:deployment[options]   # Install components from bower using previously generated bower.json
rails bower:install:development[options]  # Install both dependencies and devDependencies from bower
rails bower:install:production[options]   # Install only dependencies, excluding devDependencies from bower
rails bower:list                          # List bower components
rails bower:resolve[relative_directory]   # Resolve assets paths in bower components
rails bower:update[options]               # Update bower components
rails bower:update:prune[options]         # Update existing components and uninstalls extraneous components
rails cache_digests:dependencies          # Lookup first-level dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comme...
rails cache_digests:nested_dependencies   # Lookup nested dependencies for TEMPLATE (like messages/show or comments/_...
rails db:create                           # Creates the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the cur...
rails db:drop                             # Drops the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the curre...
rails db:environment:set                  # Set the environment value for the database
rails db:fixtures:load                    # Loads fixtures into the current environment's database
rails db:migrate                          # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false, SCOPE=blog)
rails db:migrate:status                   # Display status of migrations
rails db:rollback                         # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n)
rails db:schema:cache:clear               # Clears a db/schema_cache.dump file
rails db:schema:cache:dump                # Creates a db/schema_cache.dump file
rails db:schema:dump                      # Creates a db/schema.rb file that is portable against any DB supported by ...
rails db:schema:load                      # Loads a schema.rb file into the database
rails db:seed                             # Loads the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rails db:setup                            # Creates the database, loads the schema, and initializes with the seed dat...
rails db:structure:dump                   # Dumps the database structure to db/structure.sql
rails db:structure:load                   # Recreates the databases from the structure.sql file
rails db:version                          # Retrieves the current schema version number
rails dev:cache                           # Toggle development mode caching on/off
rails initializers                        # Print out all defined initializers in the order they are invoked by Rails
rails log:clear                           # Truncates all/specified *.log files in log/ to zero bytes (specify which ...
rails middleware                          # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rails notes                               # Enumerate all annotations (use notes:optimize, :fixme, :todo for focus)
rails notes:custom                        # Enumerate a custom annotation, specify with ANNOTATION=CUSTOM
rails restart                             # Restart app by touching tmp/restart.txt
rails routes                              # Print out all defined routes in match order, with names
rails secret                              # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically used to...
rails stats                               # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application or engine
rails test                                # Runs all tests in test folder
rails test:db                             # Run tests quickly, but also reset db
rails time:zones[country_or_offset]       # List all time zones, list by two-letter country code (`rails time:zones[U...
rails tmp:clear                           # Clear cache and socket files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:cache:clear, tmp:so...
rails tmp:create                          # Creates tmp directories for cache, sockets, and pids
```

update:
 rails : 5.0.5
 rvm:   2.4.1
 os:    mac

update:
 I ran bundle exec rails g active_admin:install
 but no reaction.

Comment: Did you install the gem, i.e. run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, i ran bundle install. But still erorrs.

Comment: What is the rails version ?

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails g active_admin:install`

Comment: I would stop Spring for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related with the spring preloader as stated in [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4608)

Restart the spring preloader and you should be able to run the activeadmin generator command.

> Command to stop spring

```
$ ./bin/spring stop
```

Answer (score 0):

add the gem to your Gemfile:
gem 'activeadmin'